# How do I add the library to link the OpenGL framework in iPhone SDK?

Tags: objective-c, linker-errors

I am trying to study OpenGL and I have the framework added, but I am getting linker errors.  I believe the issue is adding the library to the project for linking and *EVERY* time I try to add a library, I hunt around for the configuration setting forever.  Someone, please give me the simple click-n-go answer!

Comment: I thought I provided a screen shot in my original post ... try this

[IMG]http://i47.tinypic.com/2004eoz.jpg[/IMG]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linker cannot find the CAEAGLLayer framework to link against.

Add the `QuartzCore.framework` and the linker will be able to find the missing framework.

To do this right-click on the Frameworks the choose:
**Add > Existing Frameworks > QuartzCore.framework**.

[alt text http://img19.imageshack.us/img19/223/screenshot20091206at544.png](http://img19.imageshack.us/img19/223/screenshot20091206at544.png)

Comment: Thanks Brock - that is what I needed :)  I did find the list of libraries, but that is too indirect since the choices don't have names that one can be certain are related to the imported header files.  When I used your suggestion, that takes care of 'both' sides.